# Is there any way or any framework in python to create an object model from a xml?

Tags: python, xml, data-modeling, objectify

for example my xml file contains :

```
<layout name="layout1">
    <grid>
        <row>
            <cell colSpan="1" name="cell1"/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell name="cell2" flow="horizontal"/>
        </row>
    </grid>
</layout>
```

and I want to retrieve an object from the xml
for example returned object structure be like this

```
class layout(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.grid=None
class grid(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.rows=[]
class row(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.cels=[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found my answer
I used objectify in lxml package

this is a sample code:

```
from lxml import objectify

root = objectify.fromstring("""
 <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <a attr1="foo" attr2="bar">1</a>
   <a>1.2</a>
   <b>1</b>
   <b>true</b>
   <c>what?</c>
   <d xsi:nil="true"/>
 </root>
""")

print objectify.dump(root)
```

it prints:

```
root = None [ObjectifiedElement]
    a = 1 [IntElement]
      * attr1 = 'foo'
      * attr2 = 'bar'
    a = 1.2 [FloatElement]
    b = 1 [IntElement]
    b = True [BoolElement]
    c = 'what?' [StringElement]
    d = None [NoneElement]
      * xsi:nil = 'true'
```